# .replace() won't replace every instance despite /g

Tags: javascript, html, replace

So, I've got two problems with my javascript code. I'll try to make it as short as possible and only copy parts that are necessary for the problem.

I have this html code (it's not my fault that every li looks different):

```
    <li>
        <span style="font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Siehe <a href="Link 1" rel="">Text 1</a>.</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span style="font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Siehe</span> <a href="Link 1" rel="">Text 2</a>.<span style="font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;"> </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        Siehe <a href="Link 1" rel="">Text 3</a>.
    </li>
```

And here comes the necessary javascript code for my problems. First, I delete every span element. After that I want to replace the "a href" parts and increase the number of the new string.

```
var neu = document.getElementById("ausgabe").value;             
var nummer = 0;
function getNextDlcNumber() {
    return ++nummer;
}

var ersetzen = neu
.replace(/<span.*?>(.*?)<\/span>/g, "$1") // Gets rid of every span
.replace(/\s<li>\n\s\sSiehe\s*<a href=".*?" rel="">(.*?)<\/a>\.\n\s<\/li>/g, "\t<li>\n\t\tSiehe <a class=\"trophiesAnkerLink\" href=\"#dlc" + getNextDlcNumber() + "\" rel=\"\">$1</a>.\n\t</li>")); // Replaces a href with increasing dlc numbers

document.getElementById("ausgabe").value = ersetzen;
```

There are two problems with this:

1. The first and third "a href" are replaced successfully. But the second one isn't and I can't figure out why. I think it has something to do with the span tag between "Siehe" and the start of the "a" tag, however the span should get deleted due to the first replace so I'm not sure if that's what causes the problem. I tried using "Siehe\s*<a", "Siehe <a" as well as an *or* using | that contained the "`</span>`" but none of that worked.
2. The number after "#dlc" isn't increasing, it just stays at "#dlc1" even for the third one. Do I need to do that in a different way?

Here's the output after using the js:

```
    <li>
        Siehe <a class="trophiesAnkerLink" href="#dlc1" rel="">Text 1</a>.
    </li>
    <li>
        Siehe <a href="Link 1" rel="">Text 2</a>. 
    </li>
    <li>
        Siehe <a class="trophiesAnkerLink" href="#dlc1" rel="">Text 3</a>.
    </li>
```

I hope I posted every necessary information. If not, I can provide more. Thanks for your help in advance :)

Comment: btw, `+ getNextDlcNumber() +` returns a constant value build on the first call of `replace`. if you want a dynamic value, you need a function as second parameter.

Comment: This should rather be done using a DOM parser, than regular expressions.

Comment: CBroe is right, you should consider manipulating on the DOM level rather than flat strings. This will give you way more flexibility and stability.

Comment: I am using a textarea (that's the id "ausgabe") and the user can put html code into it. When a button is pressed the html code will change according to my js. Can I still use a DOM parser for this? If so, I will look into it as this is my first project with stuff like html and javascript code ever xD

Comment: @Vanyar In this case, a DOM parser will give you a bonus benefit, you can also use it as an input validator and code beautifier/formatter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As others have stated in comments and answers, using the DOM to parse the value in the `textarea` is much easier to generate the output you want. Below are two versions (DOM and text parsing) so that you can compare the simplicity of using DOM parsing versus text parsing.

(Both code versions can be rewritten and condensed. They are verbose to make the samples easier to debug.)

DOM parsing version:

```js
document.querySelector("#parse-textarea-dom").addEventListener("click", parseDom);

const inputHtml = `<li>
        <span style="font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Siehe <a href="Link 1" rel="">Text 1</a>.</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span style="font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Siehe</span> <a href="Link 1" rel="">Text 2</a>.<span style="font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;"> </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        Siehe <a href="Link 1" rel="">Text 3</a>.
    </li>`;

document.querySelector("#ausgabe").textContent = inputHtml;

let number = 0;

function getNextDlcNumber() {
  return ++number;
}

function parseDom() {
  number = 0;
  const neu = document.getElementById("ausgabe").value;
  const ulElem = document.createElement("ul");
  ulElem.innerHTML = neu;
  ulElem.querySelectorAll("li").forEach(liElem => {
    getNextDlcNumber();
    const anchElem = liElem.querySelector("a");
    anchElem.href = `#dlc${number}`;
    anchElem.className = "trophiesAnkerLink";
    liElem.removeChild(liElem.firstElementChild);
    liElem.textContent = "Siehe ";
    liElem.appendChild(anchElem);
  });
  document.getElementById("ausgabe-list-dom").appendChild(ulElem);
  document.getElementById("ausgabe-list-dom").scrollIntoView();
  document.getElementById("ausgabe-result").value = ulElem.innerHTML;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="ausgabe" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
<textarea id="ausgabe-result" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
<div>
  <button id="parse-textarea-dom">DOM Parse</button>
</div>
<ul id="ausgabe-list-dom"></ul>
```

The text parsing version for the same output:

```js
document.querySelector("#parse-textarea-text").addEventListener("click", parseText);

const inputHtml = `<li>
        <span style="font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Siehe <a href="Link 1" rel="">Text 1</a>.</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span style="font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Siehe</span> <a href="Link 1" rel="">Text 2</a>.<span style="font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;"> </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        Siehe <a href="Link 1" rel="">Text 3</a>.
    </li>`;

document.querySelector("#ausgabe").textContent = inputHtml;

// stackoverflow.com/questions/31412765/regex-to-remove-white-spaces-blank-lines-and-final-line-break-in-javascript
function condenseHTML(html) {
  return html.split('\n')
    .map(s => {
      return s.replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, "");
    })
    .filter(x => {
      return x;
    })
    .join("");
}

function getStringBetween(str, start, end) {
  const result = str.match(new RegExp(start + "(.*)" + end));
  return Array.isArray(result) && result.length > 1 ? result[1] : "";
}

let number = 0;

function getNextDlcNumber() {
  return ++number;
}

function parseText() {
  number = 0;
  const neu = document.getElementById("ausgabe").value;

  const condensed = condenseHTML(neu);

  // Remove every <span> element
  const spanRemoved = condensed.replace(/<span.*?>(.*?)<\/span>/g, "$1");

  const pattern = /<li>(.*?)<\/li>/gi;

  const ersetzen = spanRemoved.replace(pattern, (li) => {
    getNextDlcNumber();
    const anchor = li.match(/<a href=".*?" rel="">(.*?)<\/a>/gs);
    const anchorText = Array.isArray(anchor) ?
      getStringBetween(anchor[0], '\>', '\<') : "";
    const replaceStr = `<li>
    Siehe <a class="trophiesAnkerLink" href="#dlc${number}" rel="">${anchorText}</a>.
</li>`;
    return replaceStr + "\n";
  });

  document.getElementById("ausgabe-list-text").innerHTML = ersetzen;
  document.getElementById("ausgabe-list-text").scrollIntoView();
  document.getElementById("ausgabe-result").value = ersetzen;
}
```

```html
<textarea id="ausgabe" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
<textarea id="ausgabe-result" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
<div>
  <button id="parse-textarea-text">Text Parse</button>
</div>
<ul id="ausgabe-list-text"></ul>
```

Comment: Thank you for showing me the comparison :D
I think I'm beginning to know how to do it with the DOM parser. Your example really helped me out! :)

Answer (score 2):

Actually it's a very bad idea to manually parse and edit DOM elements contents, you don't have to complicate your life and reinvent the wheel.

You can use **JS built-in methods** to directly access `.href` attribute of your link elements and change it directly, without even using `.replace()` method.

This is how can be your code:

```
let elements = Array.from(document.getElementById("ausgabe").querySelectorAll("a"))
elements.forEach(a => a.href = "#dlc" + getNextDlcNumber());
```

You can see it can just be a one liner code, to do all what you were trying to achieve.

**Demo:**

```js
var nummer = 0;

function getNextDlcNumber() {
  return ++nummer;
}

Array.from(document.getElementById("ausgabe").querySelectorAll("a")).forEach(a => a.href = "#dlc" + getNextDlcNumber());
```

```html
<div id="ausgabe">
  <li>
    <span style="font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Siehe <a href="Link 1" rel="">Text 1</a>.</span>
  </li>
  <li>
    <span style="font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Siehe</span> <a href="Link 1" rel="">Text 2</a>.<span style="font-family:arial, helvetica, sans-serif;"> </span>
  </li>
  <li>
    Siehe <a href="Link 1" rel="">Text 3</a>.
  </li>

</div>
```

You can check the new values of your `links`by hovering them, et voilà.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I will keep this in mind for further practice, unfortunately I can't use it in my case as there will be other "a"-tags inside the html that is put into the textarea that shouldn't be changed. It's only the ones that have "Siehe (link)" within the them line. But this is really helpful for future projects, so thank you! :D

Comment: @Vanyar You are welcome, but even if there are other `a` elements in the HTML, within the selector in `querySelector()` you can target the right `a` elements by using classes, any way even if the HTML code is inside a textarea, you can take it, create a virtual div element, place it on it and fetch it directly with the `querySelector` to avois missleading beahoviors of `.replace()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `neu.replaceAll(pattern, replacement)`.

Doc: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replaceAll